# CheckStyle from maven: how to fail at the very end?

Tags: maven, checkstyle, multi-module

I have a multi-module maven build configured to run CheckStyle. It works, but it fails as soon as it comes across a module with a violation. How can I process all modules but not fail until the very end? I'd like to be able to see all violations without having to fix/re-run repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise to do this in your IDE, to get checkstyle violations feedback while you code, and not only late when building using Maven. Still keep maven checking for violations, and fail a build as early as possible, on first module with violations.

E.g. there is [eclipse-cs](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/), checkstyle plugin for eclipse IDE. To have both maven-checkstyle-plugin and eclipce-cs use same checkstyle configuration file, install [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) eclipse plugin and it's [extensions](http://code.google.com/p/m2e-extensions/) including one for eclipse-cs.

Comment: We do run this in IDE. In a big team though, there's always someone who takes shortcuts or just forgets.